# BioPython: How to search for a motif in a collection of Seq objects

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a list of Seq objects from BioPython and I want to search for an amino acid sequence motif within these sequences.  What is the best way to search these sequences?  My search is to find a motif like GxxxG, but that could be longer or shorter but stop at the first instance of the next G after the first G.  Using a regular expression such as G.*G will give me a results of the first G with any number of amino acids to the last found G.

```
#Some example code
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
import re

records = Seq("WALLLLFWLGWLGMLAGAVVIIVR", IUPAC.extended_protein)

search = re.search("F.*G", str(records))
print search.group()
# Want FWLG
# Get 
FWLGWLGMLAG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a lazy match.

A.*B given ABBBBBBBBBBBBBE can be though of as trying to match:

```
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBE
^-------------^
```

Going "that doesn't match" and trying one letter less

```
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBE
^------------^
```

Going "that does match" and returning it

A lazy match `A.*?B` will try and match as little as possible. In this case:

```
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBE
^^
```

A and 0 characters then B, and will be like "That's a match" and return just AB

? usually means optional, but as * is a quantifier (0 or more) ? acts upon it to make it lazy.

You want `F.*?G`

Comment: What about if there needs to be at least one of any character between, in your example, A and B?  So the output would want to be at least A.B.

Comment: @Kev you could use + for 1 or more. * is 0 or more, ? is 1 or  0 (optional), you can use {5,} to mean 5 or more times, or {5,7} to mean 5 to 7 times.

Answer (score 0):

Using a lazy quantifier is the slower method. To stop at the first occurence of `G`, you can use a negated character class instead of the dot. Example:

```
F[^G]*G
```

`[^G]` means all characters except `G`

Then you can use a greedy quantifier.

To have an idea of the speed gain, you can test the different patterns with this code:

```
import re
import cProfile

s = r'ACATCATCTATCTATACAATAAAAACTATCCCCTAACTACTACACTACTATCATCACATCATATCACTTTATATCCTAC'
for i in range(1,15):
    s = s + s

s = r'F' + s 
s = s + r'ATCTATCTATACAATAATCTATCTATACAATAATCTATCGATCTATCTATACAATAATCTATCTATACAATATCG' + s

cProfile.run('re.search(r"F[^G]+G",s)')
```